# org-mode different latex document class

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am trying to use tufte-book document class in org-mode. But for some reason, org-mode doesn't let me use it and says it is unrecognized. So I am going to the resulting *.tex* file and manually changing `article` to `tufte-book`. But doing this everytime got worrysome. So I want a way to make org-mode recognize tufte-book. I looked for the manual and found something about `org-article` class but couldn't make much sense out of it for my own problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default `org-mode` only knows about the `article`, `report` and `book` classes.  To teach it a new one you have to add an entry to it to `org-latex-classes`.  I'm not familiar with `tufte-book` but most of the time it suffices to copy the existing values and just change the `\documentclass` part.  Adding something like:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("tufte-book"
               "\\documentclass{tufte-book}"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

to your config file should enable the class

Comment: Rather than adding this to the config file, it's also possible to use 'customize-variable'. The wizard may make setting these configurations a bit easier.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work as stated (I'm using straight-use-package)...  I think it may have something to do with the order things are loaded.  Custom does make it work though.  Weird...

Comment: @Metropolis Wizard?

Comment: Yeah, not good terminology. By 'wizard' I just meant the 'customize-variable' interface.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Dye has made [Tufte-org-mode](https://github.com/tsdye/tufte-org-mode) for Org-mode export to PDF.